# How to apply move semantics while inheriting from template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, move-semantics

When I run the code below it produces the following output,
The first part used the template directly,
the second using a class that is derived from the template.
The moving semantics is not invoked in the derived class (shown in bold)

Template Dummy: initializing constructor
Template Dummy: initializing constructor
Template Dummy: empty constructor
Template Dummy: empty constructor
Template Dummy: +  operator
**Template Dummy: move assignment**
2
Template Dummy: initializing constructor
Template Dummy: initializing constructor
Template Dummy: empty constructor
Template Dummy: empty constructor
Template Dummy: +  operator
**Template Dummy: copy constructor**
**Template Dummy: copy assignment**
2

The reason, I think, is clear - naming an argument turns the argument into an lvalue, thus the template receives an lvalue and invokes a copy constructor.

The question is how to force move semantics in this case?

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  template <typename T> class Dummy {

  public:

    T val;

    Dummy& operator=(const Dummy& d){
      val = d.val;
      cout << "Template Dummy: copy assignment\n" ;
      return *this;
    }

    Dummy operator+(const Dummy &d) {
      Dummy res;
      res.val = val + d.val;
      cout << "Template Dummy: +  operator\n" ;
      return res;
    }

    // constructors
    Dummy() {
      val = 0;
      cout << "Template Dummy: empty constructor\n" ;
    }

    Dummy(const T v) {
      val = v;
      cout << "Template Dummy: initializing constructor\n" ;
    }

    Dummy(const Dummy &d) {
      val = d.val;
      cout << "Template Dummy: copy constructor\n" ;
    }

    // move semantics
    Dummy(const Dummy&& d) {
      val = d.val;
      cout << "Template Dummy: move constructor\n" ;
    }

    Dummy& operator=(const Dummy&& d){
      val = d.val;
      cout << "Template Dummy: move assignment\n" ;
      return *this;
    }
  };

  class FloatDummy : public Dummy<float> {
  public:

      FloatDummy& operator=(const FloatDummy& d){
        Dummy<float>::operator=(d);
        return *this;
      }

      FloatDummy operator+(const FloatDummy &d) {
        return (FloatDummy) Dummy<float>::operator+(d);
      }

      // constructors
      FloatDummy() : Dummy<float>() {};
      FloatDummy(float v) : Dummy<float>(v) {}
      FloatDummy(const FloatDummy &d) : Dummy<float>(d) {}
      FloatDummy(const Dummy<float> &d) : Dummy<float>(d) {}

      // move semantics
      FloatDummy(const FloatDummy&& d) : Dummy<float>(d) {}

      FloatDummy& operator=(const FloatDummy&& d){

      // here d is already an lvalue because it was named
      // thus the template invokes a copy assignment    
      Dummy<float>::operator=(d);
      return *this;
    }
  };

  int main() {
    Dummy<float> a(1), b(1);
    Dummy<float> c;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c.val << '\n';;

    FloatDummy d(1), e(1);
    FloatDummy f;
    f = d + e;
    cout << f.val << '\n';
  }
```

Comment: remove `const` from all cases of `const &&`, and use `std::move(d)` to move from `d`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move from a `const&`. To fix, simply remove `const` from all your move operations:

```
FloatDummy(FloatDummy&& d) : Dummy<float>(d) {}
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ no longer FloatDummy const&&

FloatDummy& operator=(FloatDummy&& d) { /*...*/ }
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ditto
```

The essence of moving is *taking ownership* of resources, how can you take ownership of something if you can't modify your source? Therefore, move operations do not work with `const` types by default.

You'll want to do the same for the `Dummy` class.

---

You need to call `std::move()` to cast `d` to an rvalue reference: Even though `d`'s parameter type is rvalue reference, inside the function itself `d` is pretty much considered an lvalue reference. This means that you still need to cast it to rvalue reference (the whole point of `std::move()`) when you pass it to whatever is actually consuming it.

In your case, it's right when you pass it to `Dummy<float>`'s constructor or `Dummy<float>::operator=`:

```
FloatDummy(FloatDummy&& d) : Dummy<float>(std::move(d)) {}
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^ calling std::move()
//                                                  otherwise copy ctor overload is chosen

FloatDummy& operator=(FloatDummy&& d)
{
    Dummy<float>::operator=(std::move(d));
    //                      ^^^^^^^^^ ditto
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. I also had a missing move constructor that was not copied from the template causing a copy. Now I have one **move** constructor and one **move** assignment.
Thanks!!